# The Humanoid does not move

Tags: methods, lua, roblox

So I have this dummy on Roblox Studio welded to a P90 model (a gun). ***I need this dummy to move, but when I call :MoveTo to the humanoid of this dummy it just does not move*** Any help is appreciated, Thank You!

Code:

```
local RS = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local npcSettings = require(RS.Settings)
local npcVariables = require(RS.Variables) 

local NPC = workspace:FindFirstChild("NPC Gun System")

local NPCRootPart = npcVariables.NPCRootPart
local NPCTorso = npcVariables.NPCTorso
local NPCHumanoid = npcVariables.NPCHumanoid

local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local npcProperties = {
    agroDistance = 100,
    fireRate = 0.1,
    bulletDamage = 15,
    bulletSpeed = 100,
    bulletMag = 50
}

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)

local char = plr.Character or plr.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local hum = char:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") 
local torso = char:FindFirstChild("Torso")
local humRootPart = char:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
    
    local function chaseTarget()
        NPCHumanoid:MoveTo(humRootPart.Position)
    end
    
    local function Reload()
        npcSettings.Guns.P90.Sounds.ReloadSound:Play()
        --Put an animation here if you wish!
    end
    
    local function fireP90()
        if hum.Health == 0 then return end

        local newBullet = npcSettings.Guns.P90.BulletTrail:Clone()
        newBullet.Parent = workspace
        newBullet.CFrame = npcSettings.Guns.P90.Model.FirePart.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, -1)
        newBullet.CFrame = newBullet.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(90), 0)

        local Att0 = Instance.new("Attachment")
        Att0.Parent = newBullet

        local LinearVelocity = Instance.new("LinearVelocity")
        LinearVelocity.Parent = newBullet
        LinearVelocity.MaxForce = math.huge
        LinearVelocity.Attachment0 = Att0
        LinearVelocity.VectorVelocity = npcSettings.Guns.P90.Model.FirePart.CFrame.LookVector * npcProperties.bulletSpeed

        game.Debris:AddItem(newBullet, 3)

        newBullet.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
            if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart") then
                hum:TakeDamage(npcProperties.bulletDamage)
                newBullet:Destroy()
            end
        end)

        npcSettings.Guns.P90.Sounds.GunShotSound:Play()
        npcVariables.isRunning = true
    end
    
    local function checkPositionAndFire()
        if (NPCTorso.Position - torso.Position).Magnitude < npcProperties.agroDistance then
            local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

            RunService.Stepped:Connect(function()
                NPCRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.lookAt(NPCRootPart.Position, torso.Position)
            end)
            chaseTarget()
            
            fireP90()
            
        else
            npcVariables.isRunning = false
        end
    end
    
    if torso ~= NPCTorso then   
        local bulletsFired = 0
        
        while true do
            task.wait(npcProperties.fireRate)
            
            checkPositionAndFire()
            
            if npcVariables.isRunning == true then
                bulletsFired = bulletsFired + 1

                if bulletsFired >= npcProperties.bulletMag then
                    if npcVariables.isRunning == true then
                        Reload()
                        npcVariables.isRunning = false
                    end
                    bulletsFired = bulletsFired - bulletsFired
                end 

                if npcSettings.Guns.P90.Sounds.ReloadSound.IsPlaying == true then
                    npcSettings.Guns.P90.Sounds.ReloadSound.Ended:Wait()
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Relevant Code:

```
local function chaseTarget()
        NPCHumanoid:MoveTo(humRootPart.Position)
    end

local function checkPositionAndFire()
        if (NPCTorso.Position - torso.Position).Magnitude < npcProperties.agroDistance then
            local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

            RunService.Stepped:Connect(function()
                NPCRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.lookAt(NPCRootPart.Position, torso.Position)
            end)
            chaseTarget()
            
            fireP90()
            
        else
            npcVariables.isRunning = false
        end
    end
```

I already tried calling another methods and altering its CFrame to make the humanoid of the dummy move, as i said, Im expecting to make the humanoid of the dummy move.

Comment: Is it anchored?

Comment: No, is not anchored, I checked the model and the only thing that is anchored is the humanoid that the anchor cannot be removed.